# Is there a daily fare cap on the Taipei MRT?

Tags: trains, public-transport, taiwan, fares, taipei

My wife is Taiwanese, so every couple of years we visit her family in Taipei. I generally know my way around the Taipei MRT network, so for a laugh I'm planning to attempt Taipei's equivalent of the [Tube Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_Challenge), visiting every station on the Brown, Red, Green, Orange and Blue lines in the fastest time possible (as well as the first section of the Yellow line if it's open by then).

I have an Easy Card and I'm aware that the maximum fare for a single journey is NT$65, chargeable either by distance or if you spend too long inside the network without tapping out (90 minutes?). However, there will be sections where I will be running between stations on foot. As I'll potentially be racking up a number of maximum fares, is there a daily cap on the Taipei MRT similar to the London Underground? If not, are there any other ways to have a whole day's access to the network for a fixed price, similar to a day rider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the TRTC website's [ticketing page](https://english.metro.taipei/cp.aspx?n=BECC2E7AC426F659&s=01872DBE36650923) there does appear to be a one-day unlimited ticket available for NT$150:

> You can choose when to activate the pass. Once activated by scanning at the gates, it is valid for unlimited travel on the Taipei Metro until end of service on the same day. Valid for one passenger at a time only.

So it looks like this ticket would best suit my needs for this occasion.